# Two buttons, do two different things with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

So I think i'm pretty close to the end and I have to add the series now. As you can see I have two bottoms where it says Search movie and Search seri[image: My website]

Which means I got already movies to work quite good and now im left with the series. The problem is now that I don't really know how to make so the Javascript knows that the series buttom is on and then it should take my API and give the information as it is. I already have my JS for movies done which is like this:

```
function callAjax(input) 
{ 
var url = "http://localhost:1337/search/" + input; 

$.ajax({ 
 type:'GET', 
 url: url, 
 success: function(data){ 


    if(data) {

       console.log('SUCCESS'); 
       $('#title').html("Title: " + data.title);
       $('#release').html("Release: " + data.release);
       $('#vote').html("Vote: " + data.vote);
       $('#overview').html("Overview: " + data.overview);
       $('#poster').html('<img src="' + data.poster + '" width=250     height=450 />'); 
       $('#trailer').html("Trailer: <iframe width='420' height='315' src='https://www.youtube.com/embed/" + data.trailer + "' frameborder='0' allowfullscreen>");


    $("#lblerror").addClass("hide");

            } else {
                $("#lblerror").text("No movies were found!");
                $("#lblerror").removeClass("hide");

            }
},
 error: function(request, status, err){ 
    console.log('ERROR'); 
 } 
}); 
} 


$(document).ready(function(){ 

$('#submitButton').on('click', function(e){ 
e.preventDefault(); 

var input = $('#s').val();
callAjax(input); 
}); 

});
```

I can by myself get the right methods and so on. the only problem for me right now is that I can't, or I don't know how to make so when its series, it should take information from this URL:  var url = "http://localhost:1337/search/tv" + input;

I hope I explained so its understandable.

EDIT: My HTML looks like this just to make sure so you know how you all can see that.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>MovieTrailerbase</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />

</head>

<body>

<div id="page">

    <h1>The MovieTrailer search</h1>

    <form id="searchForm" method="post">
        <fieldset>

            <input id="s" type="text" />

            <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submitButton" />

            <div id="searchInContainer">
                <input type="radio" name="check" value="site" id="SearchMovie" checked />
                <label for="SearchMovie" id="siteNameLabel">Search movie</label>

                <input type="radio" name="check" value="web" id="SearchSeries" />
                <label for="SearchSeries">Search series</label>
            </div>

        </fieldset>
    </form>

    <div id="lblerror"></div>

<aside>
<div id="title"></div>
<div id="release"></div>
<div id="vote"></div>
<div id="overview"></div>
<br>
<div id="trailer"></div> 

</aside>

<div id="poster"></div>


</div>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>


</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can send the `$('#searchSeries').prop('checked')` to the `callAjax` function, e.g:

```
var input = $('#s').val();
var isSeries = $('#searchSeries').prop('checked');

callAjax(input, isSeries);
```

And then, you can change the API call in your AJAX function, like this:

```
function callAjax(input, isSeries) 
{ 
  var url = 'http://localhost:1337/search/' + (isSeries ? '/tv' : '') + input; 
  /* ... */
}
```

---

**UPDATE**

Since you didn't understand what I said above, there is a snippet with the full code below:

```js
function callAjax(input, isSeries) {
  var url = "http://localhost:1337/search/" + (isSeries ? '/tv' : '') + input;

  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: url,
    success: function(data) {
      if (data) {
        console.log('SUCCESS');
        $('#title').html("Title: " + data.title);
        $('#release').html("Release: " + data.release);
        $('#vote').html("Vote: " + data.vote);
        $('#overview').html("Overview: " + data.overview);
        $('#poster').html('<img src="' + data.poster + '" width=250     height=450 />');
        $('#trailer').html("Trailer: <iframe width='420' height='315' src='https://www.youtube.com/embed/" + data.trailer + "' frameborder='0' allowfullscreen>");

        $("#lblerror").addClass("hide");

      } else {
        $("#lblerror").text("No movies were found!");
        $("#lblerror").removeClass("hide");
      }
    },
    error: function(request, status, err) {
      console.log('ERROR');
    }
  });
}


$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#submitButton').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var input = $('#s').val();
    var isSeries = $('#searchSeries').prop('checked');
    callAjax(input, isSeries);
  });

});
```

Comment: I will try that now ans see how it goes, but how should I do it at the end of this `$(document).ready(function(){ 

$('#submitButton').on('click', function(e){ 
e.preventDefault(); 
var input = $('#s').val();
var isSeries = $('#searchWeb').prop('checked');

callAjax(input, isSeries)


var input = $('#s').val();
callAjax(input); 
}); ` because I will prob have almost two things that are called the same?

Comment: @WeInThis I updated my answer with the full code inside a snippet.

Comment: Yeah, forgot to tell you that haha. And nice for catching me there too!

Comment: Does it work, because I see two widgets with the same `id` attribute in the HTML?

Comment: @MaxZoom where do you see two widgets with the same `id` attribute?

Comment: Yeah, I fixed it. I had to change little bit in my API to make so the Series api and Movie api matches. So I dont have to change the calls from jquery too

Comment: OK - I see it changed. I would remove the `id` attribute completely and use `$('input[name=check]:checked').val()`

Comment: Why one would use a complex selector like this one instead of simply checking by ID?

Comment: @Buzinas Because there could be more then one form on the page with the same `id` for different widgets. So using the `id` for form widget is a bad idea.

Comment: IDs should always be unique in HTML, independent on how many forms we have. Got to go now, nice talking, I'll be back later, cya! :)

Answer (score 1):

you can set your url var like this :

```
var url = "http://localhost:1337/search/" + $('input[name="check"]:checked').val();
```

Answer (score 1):

You will have to provide the value of the radio button to your API. You could easily grab the value of the radio button by using:

```
var radioSelection = $('#searchInContainer').find('input[name=check]:checked').val();
```

And then plug it into your API url with:

```
var url = "http://localhost:1337/search/" radioSelection + input;
```

Note: you will need to change the values of your radio buttons to get the desired output.

For example, with your current values and the above code, when you select 'Series', it will output "http://localhost:1337/search/web" + input.

Comment: Hmmm, I dont quite understand how I take that to my code, I was more thinking like making one function(data) { for like the movies and function(data){ for the series and pretty much just copy and paste?

Comment: Just use those two lines and replace the `var url = ...` line in your function.

Answer (score 1):

Update your ajaxCall function to something like this

**UPDATED** (from comments)

```
function callAjax(input) {
    var optionSelected = $('input[name="check"]:checked').val();
    console.log(optionSelected);

    var url;

    if (optionSelected === 'site') { // for Search movie
        url = "http://localhost:1337/search/" + input
    } else {
        // your other URL here for search series
        url = "http://localhost:1337/searchseries/" + input
    }

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: url,
        success: function (data) {
            if (data) {
                // you may have to fetch the value again here... not sure
                // var optionSelected = $('input[name="check"]:checked').val();

                if (optionSelected === 'site') {
                    handleMovieResponse(data);
                } else {
                    handleSeriesResponse(data);
                }
            } else {
                $("#lblerror").text("No movies were found!");
                $("#lblerror").removeClass("hide");

            }
        },
        error: function (request, status, err) {
            console.log('ERROR');
        }
    });
}

function handleMovieResponse(data) {
    console.log('SUCCESS');
    $('#title').html("Title: " + data.title);
    $('#release').html("Release: " + data.release);
    $('#vote').html("Vote: " + data.vote);
    $('#overview').html("Overview: " + data.overview);
    $('#poster').html('<img src="' + data.poster + '" width=250     height=450 />');
    $('#trailer').html("Trailer: <iframe width='420' height='315' src='https://www.youtube.com/embed/" + data.trailer + "' frameborder='0' allowfullscreen>");

    $("#lblerror").addClass("hide");
}

function handleSeriesResponse(data) {
    // your code for series here
}
```

Comment: Hmm, I couldnt understand that about 'site' and also I cant have the rest of the code where it takes all the information from my API aswell since its two diffrent $ atturbites

Comment: But I was thinking like, doesnt it work like do if(Checked movies)  {
to the movies information
else { to the series information?

Comment: oh, sure... if the api returns different attributes, you can call two separate functions on success... let me update my answer

Comment: Well you dont have to sir! I got it to work and I really appreciate that you took your time aswell! Also if you know doing it it would be nice too see it too :D